# Set styles to last element in ListView with sections

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with ListView styling. My ListView has sections. So I need to separate sections by some empty space. I see decision in adding marginBottom style to last element in every section. With css it would be done with :last pseudo-class. Has React Native some alternatives to do this?

Some pseudo code for example:

```
var dataSource =  new React.ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (a, b) => a !== b,
    sectionHeaderHasChanged: (a, b) => a !== b,
    getRowData: (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[rowId],
    getSectionHeaderData: (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[sectionId]
});

//test data
var sectionIds = ["clients", "properties"];
var rowIds = [["clients_1", "clients_2"], ["properties_1"]];
var dataBlob = {
    clients_1: {
        type: "client",
        title: "Andrew Chinn",
        addInfo: "xxx xxx xxx",
        image: ""
    },
    clients_2: {
        type: "client",
        title: "Karl Chinn",
        addInfo: "xxx xxx xxx",
        image: ""
    },
    properties_1: {
        type: "property",
        title: "Karl Chinn",
        addInfo: "xxx xxx xxx",
        image: ""       
    }
};


const renderSectionHeader = (data) => {
    return (
        <SomeTestHeader {...data}/>
    );
};

const renderRow = (data) => {
    return (
        <SomeTestComponent {...data}/>
    );
};

var Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <View>
            <ListView
                dataSource={dataSource.cloneWitRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds)}
                renderRow={renderRow}
                renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
            />
        </View>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `renderRow` method :

```
renderRow = (rowData, sectionId, rowId) => {
  var indexSection = _.findIndex(this.state.sectionIds, function(o) {return o === sectionId});
  if (rowId == _.last(this.state.rowIds[indexSection])) {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>{rowId}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text>{rowId}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

You can do the same for your sections with sectionId. I've set up an example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/qgUK0g).

Comment: Problem is that I do not know exact number of rows. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Also, cause I use ListView with sections, rowId is not index but key of object.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code. So I can see if it can be done ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, tell me if it works. It's a workaround, as I see no implemented solution. The link is updated too.

Answer (score 1):

ListView exposes a function called renderSeparator which renders a view/component between sections, use it to render the separator you want.

Your other option is just to give marginTop value to the view you're rendering in the renderSectionHeader

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to use renderSeparator property.
This is quote from React Native documentation:
**If provided, a renderable component to be rendered as the separator below each row but not the last row if there is a section header below.**
This made me think that it is not the thing that couldhelp me.
Could you demonstrate sample of usage?